# API gateway using Springboot

Tags: spring-boot

I have developed an intermediate API layer (acts like a Gateway) for mobile clients using WebClient with spring boot. My application retrieves the data from a third party application using REST API. The third party REST API authenticates the requests using the session token. My application has no authentication or authorization layer, it just authenticates the requests from a mobile device using the third party authentication. The mobile device passes the userid and password of My question is

1. How do we configure WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter for this usecase?
2. What are the best security practices in this scenario?

Comment: Do you need to create your own API Gateway? Because you could use eureka, In the next link, you can know more [More Info](https://spring.io/guides/gs/service-registration-and-discovery/)

Comment: Thanks for the response. The idea of using API Gateway is to consolidate the multiple third party API calls and also to use the limited information from the 3rd party API response as the complete response not required. Also not to build any complex logic at them mobile end. Can you please explain how to use Eureka for this use case?

Comment: You can use zuul API Gateway together with eureka but in your case use only zuul. [Example with zuul](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-build-an-api-gateway-with-netflix-zuul-spri)